# No cargan ficheros css

Tags: php, css, xampp

Siempre que trabajo desde XAMPP y php no se me cargan los ficheros CSS, los cuales si luego los llevo a un servidor externo veo que funcionan sin problema.

¿Sabeis si se debe a una mala configuración por mi parte, una mala programación, es un defecto de xampp...?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestro la raiz (no se si hay una manera mejor de verlo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Observo que en el error no sale plataforma (la carpeta general del proyecto), salta de PHP_WEB_MMR a CSS, pero yo en mi configuración del proyecto si lo puse como muestro a continuación y el resto de cosas si que me salen...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación muestro la llamada al fichero.css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<HTML lang="es">

<HEAD>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/menu.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/overhang.min.css" />
</HEAD>
```

Salud

Comment: muestra una captura de pantalla de tu directorio raiz

Comment: No es un defecto de XAMPP... cómo es la URL que usas para cargarlos?

Comment: @PabloLozano yo imagino que soy yo jajajaja

Comment: Mostra el código html donde intentas cargarlos

Comment: Ese no es problema, está bien puesto el link. Además cuando uso el host de internet (000web) funciona perfectamente. Solo me pasa en local

Comment: a mi me pasó eso, y resultó ser un problema del casesensitive

Answer (score 1):

Te esta faltando el directorio llamado: **Plataforma**.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Plataforma/CSS/menu.css">
```

El error que muestra la consola es porque el directorio llamado **CSS** esta en la raíz de tu proyecto, a diferencia de la captura de pantalla que muestras de tus archivos, en dónde la carpeta **CSS** esta dentro de **Plataforma**.

Comment: Comparte el código en dónde haces referencia a las hojas de estilo, así tendremos más oportunidad de detectar el error de por qué no te incluye Plataforma en la consola.

Comment: Cierto eso lo he comentado en el post, el problema es que yo si tengo ese link bien puesto. Ahora lo añado para que lo veais que antes ya me lo han comentado. Es más, se que eso está bien puesto porque en mi servidor web si que funciona, solo es en local y solo me pasa si el fichero es .php. Cuando son .html no da ese error.

Comment: Entonces puedes subir de nivel el directorio Plataforma y omitir PHP_WEB_MMR para probar, o también revisar cómo esta el path en PHP. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955716/php-setting-root-directory-for-project